# Python Plotly chart displaying data from wrong year in Animation Frame

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, stacked-bar-chart

I am making a stacked bar chart in Python using plotly. The chart contains an animation frame that allows you to drag a scroll bar to select between years, and the data will change. The dataset contains the years 2019, 2020, 2021, and 2022. The code runs correctly, but when you hover over the bars in certain years it will say the data is from a different year. For example, one of the bars in the year 2022 has data from the year 2020 in it. Here's what the code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

Role_counts = pd.read_csv('Role_counts.csv')


Role_counts = Role_counts.sort_values(by = ['Year'], ascending = [True], na_position = 'first')


fig2 = px.bar(Role_counts, x='Month', y='Count', color='Role', barmode='stack',
             animation_frame="Year",animation_group="Month",
              range_y=[0, 30], title = "Counts by Role")
```

Here's a few rows of sample data that would be in the table Role_counts. The rest of the data follows a similar pattern throughout the months and years.

| Month | Role | Year | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | Officer | 2019 | 3 |
| January | Security | 2020 | 2 |
| February | Staff | 2021 | 4 |
| March | Faculty | 2022 | 1 |

I was expecting the animation to display all of the data in the correct years. When I scroll from 2019 to 2022, all of the data in 2019 should be in the 2019 section, all of the 2020 data is in the 2020 section, and so on and so forth. That is currently not happening and I am at a loss as to why.

Comment: Added in more context. That's all there is to it.

Comment: My environment is plotly:5.13.0 latest and I tried your code. The data in the bar chart is displayed correctly. What is the current version you are using?